# HTML element specified after floating div rendered before said div

Tags: html, css

Consider this HTML snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
      <body>
        <div id="bounding-div">
          <div style="float: left">
            <h4>test1</h4>
          </div>
          <div style="float: right">
            <h4>test2</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
        <h3 style="background: #ff0000">Test</h3>
      </body>
    </html>
```

When opened in firefox, "Test" is rendered before both "test1" and "test2". I would expect that the div element with the id "bounding-div" would group the floating elements and that elements specified thereafter ought to be rendered afterwards. Why is this not the case? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Floated elements are ignored by all but other floated elements.
So the bounding-div "doesn't care" about them at all.

A solution can be to add a third div with `clear: both;` to clear the floating div's.

See here:
http://codepen.io/shippin/pen/WpMjbW

Comment: Your solution worked, thanks. I still don't get the reversed rendering order though. Is there some rule like floated elements are rendered before all other elements?

Comment: It's not a reversed rendering. You see the float elements under the `bounding-div` because you use `h4` who has by default some margin.

Comment: The element is shown at the top because it ignores the fact that the floated elements exist- so it acts as if they don't and naturally appears at the top of the page.

Comment: I think the answer is there, but I still couldn't grasp it. Why is the margin important here? Also, the indentation of "Test" just by the width of "test1" is a mystery to me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a clearfix.

```css
#bounding-div:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="bounding-div">
  <div style="float: left">
    <h4>test1</h4>
  </div>
  <div style="float: right">
    <h4>test2</h4>
  </div>
</div>
<h3 style="background: #ff0000">Test</h3>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add "clearfix" for floated elements:

```
#bounding-div::after {
  display: table;
  clear: both;
  content:"";
}
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5jsnwhzy/)

Answer (score 1):

Well that's because there is no declaration of `height` in `parent div` and neither to floated `div` even if `height` is not included then see as below, see as below,

> The float CSS property specifies that an element should be taken from
>   the normal flow and placed along the left or right side of its
>   container. When an element is floated it is taken out of the normal
>   flow of the document.It is shifted to the left or right until it touches the edge of its containing box.

**Example - 1**

```css
#bounding-div{
  background:#ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id="bounding-div">
          <div style="float: left">
            <h4>test1</h4>
          </div>
          <div style="float: right">
            <h4>test2</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
<h3 style="background: #ff0000">Test</h3>
```

I have added `background` to `parent div` but couldn't see that as both element are `floated`. Whereas if you `remove float` and replace them by `display:inline-block` or even if you won't replace then it's okay, you could see the output as `html tags are placed in page` as in example 2.

**Example -2**

```css
#bounding-div{
  background:#ccc;
}
```

```html
  <div id="bounding-div">
          <div style="display:inline-block">
            <h4>test1</h4>
          </div>
          <div style="display:inline-block">
            <h4>test2</h4>
          </div>
  </div>
<h3 style="background: #ff0000">Test</h3>
```

**Example -3**
Just add `clear:both` on new element placed after them to align this as default.

```css
h3{
 clear:both; 
}
```

```html
  <div id="bounding-div">
          <div style="float: left">
            <h4>test1</h4>
          </div>
          <div style="float: right">
            <h4>test2</h4>
          </div>
  </div>
<h3 style="background: #ff0000">Test</h3>
```